Android SwipeRefreshLayout Customize
I want to customize the SwipeRefreshLayout and use it.
NestedScrollView exists as a SwipeRefresh internal child.
When I reload SwipeRefresh by pulling, I would like to expose the image to the area like Image B, not the loading bar is created.
Usually, it will be exposed like Image A
What should I do?


